# Using icon in top left of ActionBarSherlock to navigate

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Using the developers guide found [`here`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home), I am trying to make my icon navigate back to my home screen. I currently have a button which does this, and have copy and pasted the code in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. However tapping the icon never does anything. Is this a difference in ActionBar and ActionBarSherlock?

This is the code given as an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.mainTopBluetoothState:
        Toast.makeText( this, "BluetoothState", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.mainTopAppState:
        Toast.makeText( this,  "BluetoothState",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return true;
    case android.R.id.home:
        Log.i( "In Home", "In Home" );
        killToasts();
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent( KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ));
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
```

When I tap the icon, nothing happens. The `Log` call in the code isn't ever shown in my `LogCat` either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably not enabling the ABS Activity logo to be clickable. Add this in `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Also, if you haven't done so already, read [**Implementing Ancestral Navigation**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) so you navigate up *properly* (ignore their use of `getActionBar()`, they're not using ABS, and that's the actual Android API Action Bar method).