# ActionBarSherlock: OnOptionsItemSelected doesn't recognize R.id.home

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the ActionBarSherlock library and I'm following the exact steps as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617399/enable-home-button-actionbarsherlock-sherlockfragment,) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488229/using-icon-in-top-left-of-actionbarsherlock-to-navigate) to enable navigation to the previous screen.

My code looks like this:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // This callback is used only when mSoloFragment == true (see
    // onActivityCreated above)
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // App icon in Action Bar clicked; go up
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Reuse the
                                                            // existing
                                                            // instance
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

But R.id.home is not recognized and home shows up in red. :-/ If I use the native actionbar the home declaration takes me to ids.xml file. But here the declaration is not found while I use the ActionBarSherlock Activity. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just replace  this

```
android.R.id.home
```

to

```
R.id.home
```

and check your code... run it

because

`R.layout.*` are layouts you provide (in res/layout, for example).

`android.R.layout.*` are layouts that ship with the Android SDK.

Comment: It gave me a suggestion as R.id.homeAsUp, I selected that and it has saved. I'll update this thread once I find out if it's working.

Comment: I am afraid this is not the correct answer. android.R.id.home is fine. I suspect the minSdkVersion is too low. Should be 11 or higher.

Comment: @Frank: if you have used actionbarsharelock then min sdk is 8. am i right?

Comment: According to the Android docs, android.R.id.home was introduced in 3.0. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks. You mean that the R.id.home is defined in ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I believe the right answer is missing.

It should be be `android.R.id.home` because it is a platform resource, so your code is fine.

Make sure your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher since `home` was introduced in 11.

Answer (score 1):

I remeber running into this problem and apparently its quite frequent a quick google or search through stack overflow should've given you some insight anyways check this thread out [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)
Im pretty sure your running into same problem

Comment: Brendan - My problem is not with the R error. It's concerned with ActionBarSherlock library. Try to be more specific with your answers. :) Just a suggestion. Thanks anyway.